# Xcode6 - Distributing Beta App using iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode6, testflight

I'm trying to use the Beta App Distribution following this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

I've chosen provisioning profile XC:com.example.myapp...

During the upload process, I got the following error message:

> ditto: Couldn't read PKZip signature Unable to extract archive. 
>   Please make sure /var/folders/gg/...../MyApp.pkg is valid zip or ipa archive.

Any idea what's the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to set the variable "Application requires iPhone environment" to YES

https://devforums.apple.com/message/1037708#1037708

Answer (score 2):

The answers I've found for this don't seem to be fully correct at the time of writing this.  Apple seems to have changed this around yet again breaking their own tools and costing us all time trying to figure it out!   I'll add this in addition to the answer in the hope it'll help anyone else:

Add the LSRequiresIPhoneOS as the answer states.  **But this didn't help uploading via xcode**.  My solution is to **upload via Application Loader** as follows:

1. Export the package via xcode (save as a .pkg file locally)
2. Start the Application Loader, and then click on "New In-App
   Purchase".  This will bring up a IAP manage screen.
3. Select your application, press the "manage" button.
4. In the next screen, down the bottom you'll see tabs, one being "Hosted Content".
5. This is where you can upload your pkg.  Click the choose button to select your pkg file, validate, and deliver.

This was the only way I could get it working.